# Can I see all my deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

There is a question I want to ask on Photography Stack Exchange, but I have a vague feeling that I might have asked it already a long time ago and it was closed and automatically deleted. Or I am imagining things in my head, and I might have drafted the text but never posted it.

Is there some way to see **all** my deleted questions?

I understand that Stack Exchange comes with a tool to see my *recently* deleted questions but it comes up blank. And I understand that if I had 10k reputation (like I do on Stack Overflow), I can easily answer this question by myself with the available tools. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some way to see all my deleted questions?

**No**, not unless you have enough rep to see deleted questions.

> There is a question I want to ask on Photography Stack Exchange, but I have a vague feeling that I might have asked it already a long time ago and it was closed and automatically deleted.

If you don't find the question or a similar one here already, then first consider whether it's the sort of question that's on topic and answerable, and otherwise fits here. If it is, then go ahead and ask. Your previous question would only have been closed immediately if it was a duplicate or if was close-worthy for some reason. Review the information under the *Asking* heading in the [Help Center](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help) if you're not sure what is or isn't a good question.